# Creating a relational database in MySQL for a shopping system

Tags: mysql, database-design, dynamic, relational-database

I need to create a dynamic database structure that would support different items for a shop system.

Any type of item.

EX: Shirts
Shirts would need to have sizes (s, m, l) and types (longsleeve, shortsleeve)

The price for a shirt would have to correspond to the type and size.

This same database structure would have to support a much more basic item.. like a sandwich. The sandwich only needs to have a price.

I don't see how to create a database that would be designed to support complex item structures and then more basic items.

Answer (score 1):

Faced with something with per item properties that may have nothing to do with one another, and need to be added dynamically when you add new items to the 'store' I would put general information in my tables and item specific stuff in an XML (with a schema custom to that item or possibly sub-type). Alternately you could have a key-value look up table to accomplish something similar.

For certain known business functions (price calculation) you could store the formula in a per-defined format in the item record and have it reference the specific properties (from the XML or key-value table) which need to be used to calculate them. Same for other common functions against custom / not known beforehand properties.

I did something similar to allow on custom processing of survey answers for user created surveys and it worked well, but was far more complex and fragile than you would want if it was not a requirement.

**Update**

Example (thrown together for illustration, not a recommended actual approach):

```
ItemTable
-------------
  ItemName
  BasicDescription
  CostFormula
  XMLExtendedData
```

Then XML Schema for a shirt item (not a specific stock item, but something which defines the range of this particular shirt)

```
<Shirt>
   <Sizes/> ...
   <Types/>
   <BaseCost/>
   <SizeCost/>
   <TypeCost/>
</Shirt>
```

Then a row could contain something like:

```
ItemTable
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ItemName        | BasicDescription | CostFormula           
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Edgy Cool Shirt | A cool shirt     | BaseCost*formula using XML property/node names
```

Then a `StockItems` table which link `ItemTable` and an XML set of properties with specific data about the actual item (i.e. a Small, short-sleeved, green shirt).

With all this headache in mind all the PoS systems I have had the pleasure to use relied on, very basic commodity properties to be set on items and (on the worst of them) the brute force data entry of similar items, fun things like:

```
Lumber 2x4x4 spruce: $1
Lumber 2x4x8 spruce: $2
Lumber 2x4x10 spruce: $2.5
Lumber 2x4x12 spruce: $4
Lumber 2x4x16 spruce: $99
Lumber 2x4x4 pine: $1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle unstructured per-item properties while still maintaining what is fundamentally still a relational database (and still, for all practical purposes, MySQL) is with [dynamic columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/dynamic-columns/) in MariaDB 10.0.

> A typical use case is when one needs to store items that may have many different attributes (like size, color, weight, etc), and the set of possible attributes is very large and/or unknown in advance. In that case, attributes can be put into dynamic columns.

They do not behave identically to ordinary columns, since you have to use the `COLUMN_*()` functions to get and set the values but this might be worth evaluating.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/dynamic-columns/

<sup>(This answer almost sounds like a plug, but it isn't; I have no affiliation with the MariaDB Foundation.)</sup>